# Track x and y coordinates for platformer video game interactions with pure JS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a 2d platformer game for a college project. My mates and I have been working with jQuery and pure JS. So far I can move my character to the left and right with jQuery's [`animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function, and he can jump, but I also need my character to be able to pick up objects or interact with them at certain coordinates. These objects are positioned on the screen with an absolute position with CSS. So, my question is: Can I somehow track the x and y coordinates of my character to make him interact with these objects?

Here is an example of how i'm moving my character:

```js
function checkKey(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
 //GO TO LEFT/
    case 37:
        $('#character').css('transform','scaleX(1)');
        $('#character').animate({
            left: "-=2.5%"
        })
    
        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```js
var x = $('#character').offset().left
var y = $('#character').offset().top
```

to get the character position relative to the top of the page, and do the same with the objects. Then check if they are near enough to each other to interact.